# Polymer 1.0: Disable standard features on specific components

Tags: polymer-1.0

I'm working on a project where I'm only using polymer mini features (polymer-mini.html) and a custom template engine. Now I want to use a polymer component thats relying on polymer standard features (polymer.html).

When i include the component using the polymer standard features - there are conflicts between the custom template engine and the polymer standard features.

Is there a way that I can include polymer standard for all components, but disable all polymer standard features on specific compontents? In my case, on those using the custom template engine..

Polymer feature layering:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/experimental.html

Comment: What kind of conflicts?

Comment: The custom template engine is using its own change detection lib and also using a mustache syntax similar to polymers bindings. When polymer-standard is included it seems like both "template engines" is figthing for control over the component. No errors, but erratic behaviour.